# Cisco IOS VLAN settings for Dell iDrac with shared interface

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan, ethernet, drac

We have a few Dell servers with iDrac express, and we would like to start using the iDrac features. Our network is separated into a few VLANs for our different subnets. Our management subnet is on VLAN 28, and our data subnet is on VLAN 29. I have set up iDrac express to use VLAN 28.

How can I configure the switchport to have VLAN 29 traffic untagged and also accept traffic tagged with VLAN 28?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the trunk's native vlan... assuming you are using Gig1/1...

```
interface GigabitEthernet 1/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk native vlan 29
 switchport trunk allowed vlan <list of vlans, including 28 and 29>
```